# unable to push directory

Tags: git, symfony, gitlab

I'm using gitlab to host my project, I am developing a web application using symfony, I added a bundle using composer, and of course composer downloaded the bundle and placed it under `/vendor` (for my case and for this bundle its `vendor\nomaya\social-bundle\Nomaya\`).

Now usually when I commit and push the project, the whole project is pushed (including `/vendor`, I removed it from gitignore).
But for this specific bundle, I couldn't push the `SocialBundle` folder (which is inside the `Nomya` folder).

So when I checked GitLab, it turned out that it somehow created an archive file named `SocialBundle`, and I cant removed manually, and it does not get pulled when I pull.

So how can I remove this archive and pull my directory?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it somehow created an archive file named SocialBundle,

It is not an archive but a **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)** (a [special entry in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309), which represents the SHA1 of a nested git repo: a repo within your repo)

> and I cant removed manually:

```
git pull
# No trailing slash: you are not removing a folder, but an entry in your index.
git rm SocialBundle
git commit -m "remove gitlink"
git push
```

(Then try again including your bundle)

> and it does not get pulled when I pull

Since it is not a [submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) (where the url of that nested repo would be registered in a `.gitmodule`), all git has is the SHA1 of a repo it does not know the url of.
That is why the entry remains empty.

Comment: Thank you, i could remove that gitlink, but each time i push again, i get the same gitlink, not an actual directory

Comment: @OuerghiYassine Each time you push? Or pull?

Comment: @OuerghiYassine if you still see it on the GitLab side, then you did not commit the `git rm`, as it would have recorded the deletion of `SocialBundles`. Or you did not do the `git rm` in the right folder .

Comment: after i push (after i deleted then commited), i dont see it on Gitlab, i then re-create the SocialBundles folder, and re push, i get the same gitlink

Comment: @OuerghiYassine check if there is a `.git` within `SocialBundles` on your local repo. If so, delete it (regular `rm` command, no `git` commad involved here), before add, commit and push.

Comment: finally, got it, it was the `README.md` which resulted in that in that gitlink, i removed it and it worked, thanks.